# arraylist to select an option in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

How to assign an arraylist to select an option in jsp? I found an example([how to assign arraylist to select option in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293792/how-to-assign-arraylist-to-select-option-in-jsp)) but still get empty options.

```
IndexServlet.java

@WebServlet("/IndexServlet")
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<String> databaseArrayList = new ArrayList();
        databaseArrayList.add("1");
        databaseArrayList.add("2");
        databaseArrayList.add("3");
        request.setAttribute("databaseList", databaseArrayList);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("AddManager.jsp").forward(request, response);
        System.out.println("in index servlet");
}
}
```

JspCode

```
<tr>
            <td>Subordinate employees:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="database1">
                    <c:forEach items="${databaseList}" var="databaseValue">
                        <option value="${databaseValue}">
                                ${databaseValue}
                        </option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not forwarding the request..

```
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/AddManager.jsp");          
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I change but I still have the same problem